# Organize data with pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using fastapi to create an api, and I need to adjust the output object in pydantic but I'm not getting it. My code:

```
class Obj1(BaseModel):
    d:str = None
    e:str = None

class Obj(BaseModel):
    a:int = None
    b:str = None
    c:Obj1 = None

data = {'a': 1, 'b': 'b', 'd': 'd', 'e':'e'}

obj = Obj(**data)
```

In this way, I lose the values of d and e.

```
Obj(a=1, b='b', c=None)
```

The expected value would be

```
Obj(a=1, b='b', c=Obj1(d='d', e='e'))
```

Is there any method in pydantic that I can use to make the correct transformation of the data? I tried to use root_validator to set the object's value but had errors. Tanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given `data` dictionary does not match the defined models, this one will match:

```py
data = {'a': 1, 'b': 'b', 'c': {'d': 'd', 'e': 'e'}}
```

By default `pydantic` ignores extra attributes, and you could simply do that:

```
obj = Obj(**data, c=Obj1(**data))
```

Comment: Is there no way to transform the data into pydantic? I ask because I can't change the data at the source.

Comment: Modified answer